# What does this declaration mean in python?

Tags: python-3.8

## Definition for a Node.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x: int, next: 'Node' = None, random: 'Node' = None):
        self.val = int(x)
        self.next = next
        self.random = random

def copyRandomList(self, head: 'Optional[Node]') -> 'Optional[Node]':
```

why is next and random initialized as 'Node' = None in def **init**?
Why is Optional[Node] enclosed within '' in the function declaration copyRandomList

whereas it is different in case of ListNode:

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution:
    def reorderList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> None:
```

Answer (score 1):

When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.
Please, read the following: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references